# AVL tree implementation in Python

Tags: python, tree, linked-list

Is my implementation of AVL tree correct? It is my second Python program and I am not sure if do code properly.

```
'''
Created on 30 sty 2016

AVL tree - my second python program :)

@author: stanek
'''

class Node:

    def __init__(self, data, left = None, right = None, height = 0):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.height = height

    def add_node(self, data):
        if self.data > data:
            '''Adding to left subtree'''
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.add_node(data)
                if ( self.get_left_height() - self.get_right_height() == 2):
                    ''' Then we need to balance a subtree'''
                    print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
                    if (data < self.left.data):
                        self.rotate_left()
                    else:
                        self.double_rotate_left()

        else:
            '''Adding to right subtree'''
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.add_node(data)
                if ( self.get_right_height() - self.get_left_height() == 2):
                    ''' Then we need to balance a subtree'''
                    print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
                    if (data < self.right.data):
                        self.rotate_right()
                    else:
                        self.double_rotate_right()

    def print_nodes(self):
        if self.left is not None:
            self.left.print_nodes()
        print(self);
        if self.right is not None:
            self.right.print_nodes()


    '''
    AVL methods
    '''
    def get_right_height(self):
        if self.right is None:
            return -1
        else:
            return self.right.height

    def get_left_height(self):
        if self.left is None:
            return -1
        else:
            return self.left.height

    def set_height(self):
        self.get_height = max( self.left.get_height, self.right.get_height ) + 1

    def rotate_right(self):
        print("rotating right",self.data);
        temp = self
        self = self.right
        self.right = temp
        self.right.set_height
        self.set_height

    def rotate_left(self):
        print("rotating left",self.data);
        temp = self
        self = self.left
        self.left = temp
        self.left.set_height()
        self.set_height()

    def double_rotate_right(self):
        print("double rotating right",self.data);
        temp = self.left
        self.left = temp.right
        temp.right = self
        self = temp
        self.right.set_height
        self.set_height

    def double_rotate_left(self):
        print("double rotating left",self.data);
        temp = self.right
        self.right = temp.left
        temp.left = self
        self = temp
        self.left.set_height
        self.set_height

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)

class binary_tree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.root

    def add(self, data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            self.root.add_node(data)

    def print_all(self):
        if self.root is None:
            print("Empty tree")
        else:
            self.root.print_nodes();


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = binary_tree();
    b.add(1)
    b.add(2)
    b.add(4)
    b.add(6)
    b.add(3)
    b.add(5)
    b.print_all()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you receive some helpful answers.

Comment: Can't you answer? Or just trying to increase number or posts? O.o

Comment: Excuse me? I'm just trying to extend a friend and opening welcome to a new user in hope that you will enjoy using this site and will continue to come back and contribute to its quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bug**

No, it is not correct:

```
self.right.set_height
```

`set_height` is not run due to the lack of parenthesis, hence the height is not correctly set.

**Swapping**

In many places such as for example:

```
    temp = self
    self = self.right
    self.right = temp
    self.right.set_height
    self.set_height
```

You are swapping values in an obfuscated manner, just use the built-in `a, b = b, a` syntax:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 2
>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a, b
(2, 1)
```

**Naming**

Universally, names of classes are written in `PascalCase`, and you should really stick to it, even if the compiler does not enforce it:

```
binary_tree -> BinaryTree
```

**`get`ters**

Getters are highly frowned upon in Python. Values are generally accessed directly.

If you really do not want the user to access values directly you may make them "private" by prefixing `__` and letting a `@property` return them.

**Decide for your `nil` values**

`None` is the standard `nil` (nothing) value in Python but in `get_right_height` you return -1 if the value is`None`. If so just make the default `-1` and remove the getter as suggested above.

**Repetition Repetition**

You repeat `b.add` 6 times, use a loop to avoid such waste.

---

There must be a way to avoid repetition in the below code-blocks, the problem is that you have duplicate functions for left and right, maybe a single rotate function could help you here.

```
        '''Adding to left subtree'''
        if self.left is None:
            self.left = Node(data)
        else:
            self.left.add_node(data)
            if ( self.get_left_height() - self.get_right_height() == 2):
                ''' Then we need to balance a subtree'''
                print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
                if (data < self.left.data):
                    self.rotate_left()
                else:
                    self.double_rotate_left()
```

---

```
        '''Adding to right subtree'''
        if self.right is None:
            self.right = Node(data)
        else:
            self.right.add_node(data)
            if ( self.get_right_height() - self.get_left_height() == 2):
                ''' Then we need to balance a subtree'''
                print("Rebalancing after inserting", data)
                if (data < self.right.data):
                    self.rotate_right()
                else:
                    self.double_rotate_right()
```

Comment: But when I write "    if ( self.right.height - self.left.height == 2): " I have got an error:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'height' because None object hasnt got height